# yum update error Red Hat 6.4

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, yum

I have just upgraded my system from Red Hat 5.8 to 6.4. Upon issuing the command yum update I get the following message

```
This system is receiving updates from Red Hat Subscription Management.
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
rhel-6-workstation-rhev-agent-rpms                                                                                                                        | 2.8 kB     00:00     
rhel-6-workstation-rpms                                                                                                                                   | 3.8 kB     00:00     
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libedit.x86_64 0:2.11-4.20080712cvs.1.el6 will be updated
---> Package libedit.x86_64 0:20090923-3.0_1.el5.rf will be an update
---> Package libffi.x86_64 0:3.0.5-3.2.el6 will be updated
---> Package libffi.x86_64 0:3.0.9-1.el5.rf will be an update
---> Package perl-Test-Harness.x86_64 0:3.17-129.el6 will be updated
---> Package perl-Test-Harness.noarch 0:3.22-1.el5.rf will be an update
---> Package perl-Test-Simple.x86_64 0:0.92-129.el6 will be updated
---> Package perl-Test-Simple.noarch 0:0.98-1.el5.rf will be an update
---> Package portreserve.x86_64 0:0.0.4-9.el6 will be updated
---> Package portreserve.x86_64 0:0.0.5-2.el5.rf will be an update
---> Package python-beaker.noarch 0:1.3.1-6.el6 will be updated
---> Package python-beaker.noarch 0:1.5.3-1.el5.rf will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.4 for package: python-beaker-1.5.3-1.el5.rf.noarch
---> Package python-mako.noarch 0:0.3.4-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package python-mako.noarch 0:0.3.5-1.el5.rf will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.4 for package: python-mako-0.3.5-1.el5.rf.noarch
---> Package python-markupsafe.x86_64 0:0.9.2-4.el6 will be updated
---> Package python-markupsafe.x86_64 0:0.11-1.el5.rf will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.4 for package: python-markupsafe-0.11-1.el5.rf.x86_64
---> Package python-paramiko.noarch 0:1.7.5-2.1.el6 will be updated
---> Package python-paramiko.noarch 0:1.7.6-1.el5.rf will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.4 for package: python-paramiko-1.7.6-1.el5.rf.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: python-mako-0.3.5-1.el5.rf.noarch (rpmforge)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.4
           Installed: python-2.6.6-36.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201301301459.x86_64/6.4)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.5-3.el6.i686 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.5-3.el6_0.2.i686 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.6-20.el6.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.6-29.el6.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.6-29.el6_2.2.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.6-29.el6_3.3.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               python(abi) = 2.6
Error: Package: python-paramiko-1.7.6-1.el5.rf.noarch (rpmforge)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.4
           Installed: python-2.6.6-36.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201301301459.x86_64/6.4)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.5-3.el6.i686 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.5-3.el6_0.2.i686 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.6-20.el6.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.6-29.el6.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.6-29.el6_2.2.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.6-29.el6_3.3.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               python(abi) = 2.6
Error: Package: python-beaker-1.5.3-1.el5.rf.noarch (rpmforge)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.4
           Installed: python-2.6.6-36.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201301301459.x86_64/6.4)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.5-3.el6.i686 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.5-3.el6_0.2.i686 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.6-20.el6.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.6-29.el6.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.6-29.el6_2.2.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.6-29.el6_3.3.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               python(abi) = 2.6
Error: Package: python-markupsafe-0.11-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.4
           Installed: python-2.6.6-36.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201301301459.x86_64/6.4)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.5-3.el6.i686 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.5-3.el6_0.2.i686 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.6-20.el6.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.6-29.el6.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.6-29.el6_2.2.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.6-29.el6_3.3.x86_64 (rhel-6-workstation-rpms)
               python(abi) = 2.6
```

I'm not sure what is going on or where to start in tracking down the issue. I think there may be a problem with a repository in /etc/yum.repos.d/. I'm not sure why the message says package_blah.el6 will be updated, package_blah.el5.rf will be an update. Surely el6 will be the update

Also when I try remove python `yum remove python.x86_64` I get a very odd error `Error: Trying to remove "yum", which is protected`

Comment: It doesn't, it says that 1.7.5 will be updated and 1.7.6 will be an update. Your problem is that some packages seem to depend on python 2.4 and you will install 2.6. Is a fresh install an option?

Comment: The system version of python is 2.6. A fresh install of red hat? I guess that is possible as I only updated this morning. Nothing to lose

Answer (score 1):

As I cannot comment,I am answering,
 You may try

```
#yum reinstall python
```

before

```
#yum update
```